# Does the element exist in the Galois Field?

Tags: analysis, galois-theory, finite-fields

Let p be a prime positive integer and let a be an element of GF(p). Does there necessarily exist an element b of GF(p) satisfying b^2=a?

So, taking a element of GF(p), can we find a b element of GF(p) s.t. a=b^2

I know that C(complex) has this property: for every w element of C, there exists z element of C s.t. z^2=w.

I'm not absolutely sure how to use this, I'm assuming proof by contradiction????

Comment: Hint: all the $p-1$ nonzero elements of $\mathbb F_p$ can be represented as $\alpha^i$ for some $i, 1 \leq i \leq p-1$.  The given element (assumed to be nonzero) $a$ is thus of the form $\alpha^i$ for some $i$. Assuming that $p > 2$ and so $p-1$ is even, which of the elements $\alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3, \alpha^4, \cdots, \alpha^{p-1}$ have square roots and which don't?

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$.

If $G$ has a non-trivial element $a$ of order $2$, then when we square all the elements of $G$ we have $a^2=1^2=1$, we get at most $n-1$ different results (by counting), and there must be some element of $G$ which is not a square. This happens whenever $G$ has even order, so no group of even order has every element a square.

Your group has even order.

---

Conversely if every element has odd order, then every element is a square. Suppose $x^p=1$ where $p\gt 1$ is odd, then $\left(x^{\frac {p+1}2}\right)^2=x$