# Does there necessarily exist an element $b$ of the GF(p) satisfying $b^2 = a$?

Tags: linear-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

The question is given below:

> [image]

All I know about this field id that its order is even $p-1$. And I think if we are speaking about an element other than the identity then this is in general not true (I tried the group $\mathbb{Z_{3}}$ with the addition operation.)

**My questions are:**

1- Is the question with respect to multiplication operation?

2- should $a$ and $b$ be distinct?

**Note 1:**

This question was in a linear algebra book.

**Note 2:**

I have found the answer of this question here [Does the element exist in the Galois Field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829993/does-the-element-exist-in-the-galois-field)
but I did not understand it and it did not answer the questions I asked above. Also, I think that the answer if the question has answer no should be given by a counterexample, not by proof as I can see in the answer to the mentioned link.

Finally, could anyone help me with that question, please?

Comment: 1) Yes, squaring is multiplication. 2) No, they need not be distinct.   $p=3$ is a good place to look for a counterexample.

Comment: So the answer is no, what about the link I mentioned, why they are not using a counterexample argument? @RobertIsrael

Comment: In the link, the user who answered wanted to put the question into a more general setting and to give a more informative answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking if $a$ is a quadratic residue $\bmod p$.  If $p=2$, yes.

If $p$ is odd, not always.   See Euler's criterion [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue).